# Windows 7 Drive permissions (alternative to group policy) block access to internal OS Drives from external OS

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, group-policy, restrictions

Windows 7 admin user (version without group policy)

Hi, i want to block access (read write view etc) to the internal OS drive (boot & C:) from external OS drives pluged in.
The external OS can both see and access the internal boot and main drive now.
The Question is how to stop this from the main internal OS when gpedit.msc is not an option?

Tried using the security tab
computer > properties > security >
Tried changing advanced>  owner, permissions,auditing and effective permissions to named/admin of internal OS, but internal OS is still visible/able to write to from external OS.

Apprechiate a step by step guide very much.

Answer (score 1):

File permissions are OS-centric, so permissions set by one OS can be ignored and/or overridden by other OSs.

So to directly answer your question -- short of implementing full-disk encryption, you can't stop it.

Providing you with a step-by-step guide on how to implement disk encryption is beyond the scope of SU's Q&A format. Look into Bitlocker and alike.

Comment: Just want to block it from windows to stop access/read/write, not encrypt. Hard to believe the Internal Windows OS permissions can just be ignored. Thanks for your reply thechie007, anyone know a workaround?

Comment: It is useless to try to do that inside the "internal" OS, simply because when you boot into an OS on an external disk, the "internal" OS is not running. There might be some sort of disk locking/password facilty at the BIOS/disk controller level, if you have the right hardware.